# STM Cortex M7 memory map

Tags: stm32, cortex-m7

I suppose this is simple one, but for me as first time reader of STM32F769 datasheet it is confusing. Memory map in [this](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/group0/96/8b/0d/ec/16/22/43/71/DM00224583/files/DM00224583.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00224583.pdf) datasheet declares ITCM RAM at zero address, while [this](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/group0/78/47/33/dd/30/37/4c/66/DM00237416/files/DM00237416.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00237416.pdf) programming manual (pg. 32) declares that zero memory is code space (which by my opinion must not be RAM). 
My expectation is that's all about some kind of aliasing, however didn't find confirmation in datasheets. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cortex-M can certainly execute code from RAM, so "code space" can be RAM. In fact, the "ITCM" is a RAM block specifically designed to contain (performance-critical) code which the processor can access efficiently. Since the RAM is of course volatile, the application has to initialize it with code e.g. from flash or some other external source before executing it.

Comment: If CPU starts with PC defined at 0x0000004 location, then how could it expect something "reasonable" in RAM at that address, after power up ? Seems I still miss something.

Comment: If you wrote something there using JTAG/SWD. Typically you start an application from flash (0x08000000) which then writes something into the ITCM and calls it - typically only some functions, since the ITCM may be too small for a complete application.

Comment: I wrote nothing- I just asked myself how application can start with accidental vector addresses in RAM (after power up).

Comment: It can't. You need to write something first, either via SWD/JTAG or by starting an application from flash that writes something.

Comment: "..or by starting application from flash". I thought that CPU starts at whatever address it find at 0x00000004. How can it start from flash, which is not at 0 ?

Comment: It depends on the BOOT pins. IIRC you'd typically map the flash memory to 0.

Comment: Huh - that could be the missing stone. Which means further reading, to clarify the matter.

Comment: Now I tried simple code using Keil MDK5 simulator. Vector table is settled at 0 (in RAM) and BOOT pin / BOOT_ADDRx direct CPU to start from 0. The question is how vector table get filled ? I don't have any hardware but suppose the same will happen with JTAG.

Comment: The simulator probably has some magic to pre-fill the simulated RAM. In real hardware, you'd have to fill it via JTAG. However, what is your actual goal here? Why not simply put an application into flash, which then writes some code into the RAM and calls it as necessary?

Comment: I'm in the process of purchasing hardware, then I'll try. Even when I put my app in flash, I don't know how to define SP which is expected to be at 0, after power up (and 0 is RAM).

Comment: Set the `BOOT` pin to 0, then (by default) the address `0x00200000` which is flash will be booted. Then, put the initial SP into `0x00200000` (i.e. first flash word), the address of the reset handler at `0x00200004` and everything should be fine; just ignore the ITCM at address 0. See chapter 2.5 in the reference manual.

Comment: I've red the chapter already, but what I understood from your answer is that start SP value is not obliged to be at absolute 0, but at 0  *RELATIVE* to boot region I use. Am I right ?

Comment: I think so. The STM32F76/F77 seem to be special in this regard - 0 is always ITCM-RAM and the BOOT pin decides which address is booted; other models _remap_ the flash or RAM to address 0, and 0 is always booted.

Comment: A few simple words that I think should be emphasized in RM0410 document (or I missed them). If that so, then all pieces come into their place. My reputation score prevents me from adding points to your score, unfortunately.

Comment: When you use an example/template project from an IDE and an eval board, everything will probably be setup up correctly anyways and you don't have to worry about these details when getting started...

Comment: @Djole I've run into the same [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/700185/where-should-the-interrupt-vector-table-be-placed-in-memory-on-stm32h7a3rgt6-chi/) I think the answer is that the manual is simply wrong for some chips. The vector table is not necessarily at 0 at reset, it is for most stm32 chips which then have address 0 mapped to the start of flash, but that's not the case for a few select ones including the STM32H7A3 and the one you're using.