# Where should the interrupt vector table be placed in memory on STM32H7A3RGT6 chips?

Tags: stm32, embedded, interrupts, flash, firmware

According to the [STM32H7 programming manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/pm0253-stm32f7-series-and-stm32h7-series-cortexm7-processor-programming-manual-stmicroelectronics.pdf) "On system reset, the vector table is at address 0x00000000."

But at the same time the [STM32H7A3 reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0455-stm32h7a37b3-and-stm32h7b0-value-line-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) says in it's memory map description that ITCM RAM is mapped at address 0x00000000, not flash.

How can both of these be true at the same time? I can only write to the flash areas of the memory when installing my firmware since the ITCM ram is not persistent. So how can I ensure my interrupt vector table ends up at address 0 before any code runs?

Comment: I’d suggest using stmcube to build a simple application. You can then look at the linker script and startup code. Then you can copy them into your project.

Comment: stmcube doesn't work on my computer unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the programming manual is simply wrong.

It's true for most STM32 chips the vector table is read from `0x00000000` and that address gets mapped to the start of flash (depending on the boot configuration) but this is not the case on the STM32H7A3 and some other chips like the STM32F769. Here the vector table still should be at the start of flash which is `0x08000000` (for normal boot config) but address `0x00000000` does NOT get mapped there and is instead used for TCM RAM.

And contrary to Ben's answer, the reset vector is fetched from the vector table at the start of flash(for normal boot config), just like on other STM32 arm mcus.

Comment: Your last sentence is definitely wrong.  The reset vector is fetched from the vector table identified by the BOOT pin and the BOOT_ADD0/1 option bytes, which can be but does not need to be the start of flash.  You've shown no evidence that the programming manual is wrong, the initial value of VTOR may well be 0x0000_0000 as it claims.  But you can't ignore section 2.6 of the reference manual... the reset vector doesn't use VTOR, it uses the boot address. Only if that boot address is automatically copied to VTOR and used to find all other interrupt vectors, can you say that the manual is wrong.

Comment: The programming manual says "On system reset, the vector table is at address 0x00000000." There is no vector table there and it can't be put there at reset, therefore it's wrong. All other interrupt vectors also work when they are at 0x08000000 (with normal boot config)

Comment: Alternative perspective: The reset vector is not read from the vector table, but from the boot structure/table found at the boot address controlled by BOOT pin and the BOOT_ADD0/1 option bytes.   However I did find some other information (not authoritative) that the boot address becomes the initial value of VTOR, and if true that does make the programming manual wrong.

Comment: I don't think any of the documents mention a boot table or boot structure distinct from the vector table as found on most(all?) other STM32 chips. I'm just saying the vector table needs to be at 0x8000000(configurable by boot pin and option bytes, but in no case is it at 0x00000000 at reset and it's not mapped from there either like some other chips). And I've tested it on a genuine chip, you don't need to relocate anything to 0x00000000 or change the value of VTOR for other interrupts to work.

Answer (score 2):

The chip's own reference manual is correct, of course.  By default the chip will boot from the base of Flash memory, 0x0800_0000.

The missing detail is found in section 2.6 Boot configuration:

[image]

and

[image]

This doesn't mean that the general statement "On system reset, the vector table is at address 0x0000_0000" is wrong.  It just means that the reset vector is not fetched from the vector table in the usual way for ARM processors, but determined through special logic.

Once your software starts executing, it can setup the `VTOR` register correctly as @danmcb mentioned.  As long as this is done before interrupts are enabled, the default location for the vector table doesn't matter.

Comment: So does this mean that at address `0x0800_0000` (the beginning of flash) there should be the vector table? Or should it be the boot/startup code directly?

It's the latter right? In that case I can, instead of setting `VTOR`, just copy the vectors from flash to `0x0000_0000`, right?

Comment: @ultraturbonoob: Unfortunately the documentation isn't clear whether the "boot address" should be occupied by a data structure or actual executable instructions.  (Some processor architectures solve this by making the vector table executable, i.e. it contains jump instructions instead of function pointers.  ARM is not one of those.)

Comment: I did eventually find in section 4.3.4 the following statement: "In Standard mode, the user memory contains the application code and data, while the system memory is loaded with the STM32 bootloader. When a reset occurs, **the core jumps to the boot address configured through the BOOT pin and the BOOT_ADD0/1
option bytes.**"  So that implies it should be actual executable code at that address, not a vector table.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/elzoughby/STM32H7xx-Startup) which puts a vector table at the start of flash, not code. But I suppose it's possible that this never actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

"Privileged software can write to the VTOR to relocate the vector table start address to a different memory location, in the range 0x00000000 to 0xFFFFFF80."

Generally, I would expect the STM toolchain for the chip you are programming to handle this for you. If you are using STMCUBE I believe that the right code is generated, but of course check the sources.

Comment: The table needs to be in the right place before software runs. The software can only be executed if the vectors point to it in the first place. I'm not using stmcube.

Comment: @ultraturbonoob why are you not using it? it's a pretty decent tool.

Comment: It doesn't work on my system and also afaik it only generates C code and I'm using a different programming language.

Comment: @ultraturbonoob "The software can only be executed if the vectors point to it in the first place" is true for most ARM processors, but not this one.  This one ignores the reset vector inside the vector table.

Comment: How do you know it ignores the reset vector? All examples of stm32h7 startup code I can find use the reset vector in the usual way like with other stm32 chips.

Answer (score 0):

If so, then H7 and H7A are different.

But what is more important is that the code your MCU runs is free to choose where the interrupt table is and how it is used.

Possible options are, the vector table is set to point to Flash memory, or, the  vector table is copied to ITCM. All this may happen behind the scenes so you don't have to worry about it.

It basically means, whatever your application code does, the startup code that runs before main() function sets up the necessary environment for you.

Comment: STM32H7 is a series and the STM32H7A3 line is a part of it so both documents should apply to my MCU. I'm not sure what you mean by happen behind the scenes, I've not written any startup code yet and it would still need the vectors to point at it to be able to run.

Comment: I believe that what Justme means is that startup code will generally be generated by the toolchain (i.e. the STM tools including STMCUBE). Even if for some reason you want to do it yourself, it would probably save you a lot of time and frustration to use this (or a working demo project) as a start point. It should just not be that difficult to get this going. You do not have to start from scratch.